# loop once per startup for stepper motor

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

First of all sorry that i dont know much about programming, most of my codes are just copy paste. And of course, i know this question has been asked before, but while using this code:

```
#include <AccelStepper.h>

AccelStepper stepper (1,7,6);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
 
 stepper.setMaxSpeed(100);
 
 stepper.setAcceleration(20);
 
  stepper.runToNewPosition(100);
 
 delay (1000);
 
stepper.runToNewPosition(0);
 
delay(1000);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

The code worked perfectly once but after resetting the power the code doesnt work in a way that my stepper motor just idles.  Obviously what I want is for the stepper motor to execute the code once per power on. Is there something that i miss? many thanks!

Comment: I have never used a stepper motor but check the wiring again and insted of using arduino for programing use platform.io it will help you to understand and complete the code faster it at least helped me a lot

Comment: run an example code from the arduino IDE just to verify hardware

Comment: don't forget that there is no feedback from the motor .... maybe the driver chip is unpowered or it is incorrectly connected or it is defective

Comment: For setup() there's no difference between `power on` and `reset`.
Eventually there are subtle ones (hardware dependent -> reason of reset), but not on the Arduino layer.